# Display Custom HTML in <head> From Controller in Yii

Tags: javascript, php, yii, clientscript

We are using Yii for our project. I am trying to conditionally register two JS scripts/assets in the header: one for IE8 and one for other browsers - using conditional comments (e.g. `<!--[if lte IE 8]>`).

However, I am only familiar with `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile` and `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript`, none of which exposes a way to surround the registered script with a conditional comment.

I tried directly doing `echo` at the start of the controller action:

```
echo '<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="'.$assetsPath . '/charts/r2d3.js'.'" charset="utf-8"></script><![endif]-->';
```

However, when I look in the source the script is displayed at the top of the document (before even `<html>`). If possible, I'd like to display it in `<head>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following extension

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ewebbrowser/

I put the file in component. Then just do in the code

```
$b = new EWebBrowser();
if($b->platform == "Internet Explorer" && $b->version == "8.0") {//you could explode version at the . I guess, however not sure if there is even a version 8.x or whatever
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile("path/to/script");
} else {
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile("path/to/otherscript");
}
```

I did test this with the current IE, Firefox and Chrome browser. I can not ensure this would work with other version of these browser. It two years old, but it still seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

You can set this in head as following,

**Go to ->views->layouts->main.php**

Simple add what ever the content you need after,

i.e

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"><![endif]
[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]
[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]
[if gt IE 8]><html class="no-js"> <![endif]
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
</head>
```

or if you need to check a browser version, in a controller and append scripts. this way would also work.

define this in controller,

```
public function beforeRender( $view ) {
//condition to check the browser type and version
if($browser = 'ie' && $version = '8') {
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/js/script.js');
    return true;
}
}
```

// havent tested the second option. but should work.

you can check the browser type and version with any of the following,

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
?>
```

check this link, http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php#101125

Answer (score 0):

This is not the optimum method, but you can achieve you goal using following code:

If you want above conditional statement for particular **Controller**, then:

Under you layouts/main.php

```
<?php if (Yii::app()->getController()->getId() == 'Your Controller Name'): ?>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/ie.css" media="screen, projection" />
<![endif]-->
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you want above conditional statement for **Action** of particular **Controller**, then:

Under you layouts/main.php

```
<?php if (Yii::app()->getController()->getId() == 'Your Controller Name' && Yii::app()->getController()->getAction()->getId() == 'Your Action Name'): ?>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/ie.css" media="screen, projection" />
<![endif]-->
<?php endif; ?>
```